# Powershell - inconsistent output from the same code

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this is a noob question, but I've noticed some seemingly inconsistent behavior and I'd love to understand why.

I have a little bit of PowerShell meant to test network connectivity.  I define an array of IP addresses and an array of servernames, and I feed them to test-netconnection via invoke-command, like so:

```
$cred=get-credential

$results=@()
#insert endpoints here:
$ep=@"
10.1.1.123
10.1.1.124
"@ -split "`n" | % { $_.trim() }

#Source servernames go here:
$c = @" 
SERVER1
SERVER2
"@ -split "`n" | % { $_.trim() }
$c=$c|%{$_+".domain.contoso.com"} #append FQDN
$sb={$args|%{Test-NetConnection $_ -port 1234}} #define scriptblock
$output=Invoke-Command -cn $c -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $ep -ScriptBlock $sb
$results+=$output|sort-object pscomputername, remoteaddress|format-table  pscomputername,sourceaddress, remoteaddress, remoteport, tcptestsucceeded
$results
```

So if I run this, I get a nice little formatted table of results, except my sourceaddress is some kind of ugly MSFT_NetIPAddress object.

But this is the weird thing - if I run test-netconnection "by hand" at any point, suddenly the behavior changes and I get an IP address for Sourceaddress instead.

Even weirder, the display behavior for my **existing** output variable changes.  It goes from showing me all the members of each element in the array to only showing the common ones that you usually see when you run test-netconnection.

What's up with that?  And more importantly, how do I get the  IP address to display reliably?

Comment: [`Format-Table`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table) returns **format objects** that represent the table. Use `select-object` instead and then format _final_ output.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but I'm not sure it's relevant to my issue, given that the variability of the members displayed is seen when displaying the $output variable - before format-table comes into play.

In other words, if I look at $output after running these commands, I see *all* the members, and SourceAddress is displayed as a MSFT_NetIPAddress object.  If I then execute test-netconnection from the commandline, and look at $output again, the behavior changes, fewer members are displayed, and SourceAddress becomes an IP address.

Comment: Maybe there's some default behavior which is not defined until the command is run locally?  Is there some way to set the display behavior programmatically other than just running test-netconnection otherwise-unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) `{$_.sourceaddress.IPAddress}`:

```
$output | 
  Sort-Object pscomputername, remoteaddress |
    Format-Table -Property pscomputername, 
      {$_.sourceaddress.IPAddress},
      remoteaddress, remoteport, tcptestsucceeded
```

You can [use a hash table to add calculated properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0#description) to an object before displaying it and *to specify the **column headings*** in the table. To add a calculated property, use the `Property` or `GroupBy` parameter.

```
$output | 
  Sort-Object pscomputername, remoteaddress |
    Format-Table -Property pscomputername, 
      @{Name='sourceaddress';Expression={$_.sourceaddress.IPAddress}},
      remoteaddress, remoteport, tcptestsucceeded
```